# ¿Cómo acortar escala de un eje secundario en matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, gráficas, plot

tengo el siguiente código para 3 funciones, dos van con la misma escala (eje Y principal) y otro va con un eje Y secundario.

Me gustaría acortar la escala del eje Y secundario; que la escala del eje no llegue a toda la longitud como el eje principal, sino que se queda a la mitad o a un cuarto.

No puedo separar las gráficas en otro subgráfico, tienen que entrar todas dentro.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8))

plt.xticks([69,146,277])

#Gráficas eje Y principal (van de 0 a 1)
df['CSWI_P'].plot(color='r')
df['CSWI_A'].plot(ax=ax,color='g')

#Gráficas eje Y secundario (van de 0.7 a 2)
sec_ax=ax.twinx()
sec_ax.plot(df.index,df['DPV'],color='gray')

plt.show()
```

[image: Gráfica actual]

**Así debería verse**:

[image: Cómo debería verse]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el método twinx() de la instancia de AxesSubplot que corresponde al eje principal.

Por ejemplo:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generamos algunos datos aleatorios para dibujar en el gráfico
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.arange(10)
y1 = np.random.rand(10)
y2 = np.random.rand(10)

# Creamos el gráfico
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,8))

# Dibujamos las gráficas en el eje Y principal (va de 0 a 1)
ax.plot(x, y1, color='r')

# Creamos el eje Y secundario y dibujamos las gráficas (va de 0 a 100)
sec_ax = ax.twinx()
sec_ax.plot(x, y2, color='g')
sec_ax.set_ylim(0, 20)

# Mostramos el gráfico
plt.show()
```

Comment: Al final lo que hago es que la escala es tan granda que la gráfica queda por debajo de las otras.

No era lo que buscaba, pero ajustando se ve bien. Muchas gracias!